# How can I figure out the full call stack with the current IP and BP registers?

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, profiler, callstack

I am doing a simple experiment on Ubuntu LTS 16.04.1 X86_64 with GCC 5.4.

The experiment is to get full call stack of a running C programme.

What I have done is:

- Using ptrace's PTRACE_ATTACH & PTRACE_GETREGS to suspend a running C programme and get its current IP and BP.
- Using PTRACE_PEEKDATA to get data at [BP] and [BP+4] (or +8 for 64 bits target), so that I can have the calling function's BP and the return address.

Because the BPs are a chain, I should be able to get a sequence of return addresses. After that, by analyzing the address sequence with listing file or dwarf data, I should finally be able to figure the full call stack. Something like 'main --> funcA --> funcB --> funcC ...'.

My problem is, this works fine if the call stack is totally inside my test programme's code. I mean the case when every function is written by me. However, if the test programme is stopped in a CRT or system API, such as 'scanf' or 'sleep', the BP chain no longer works.

I checked the disassambly and noticed that CRT or system API functions do not establish stack frame by 'push ebp' and 'mov ebp,esp' like what my functions do. No wonder why the above approach does not work. But I cannot explain why GDB can still work properly in such case?! So there must be many things I do not know about Linux C programme's call stack.

Could you figure my mistake/misunderstanding? Or could you simply suggest some articles/links for me to read? Thank you very much.

Comment: By the way, although gdb is strong enough to get call stack under any circumstances, I noticed pstack seems as weak as my experimental programme. Feeling better :)

Comment: gdb is probably using some DWARF metadata. An empirical approach may be to scan the stack bottom-up for an address that falls in the middle of a function of your program (not the beginning though, it would be a pointer-to-function parameter).

Comment: @MargaretBloom Haha, yes yes! This brutal approach really should work. I didn't think of it. It seems a little bit crazy (inefficient), but it works at least. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hmm, I guess if you exclude addresses that are the start of a function, your risk of false-positives should be very low.  Margaret's idea is interesting.  There's no advantage to keeping data mixed with code (other than immediate operands), so there's no reason I can think of that you'd put middle-of-function addresses on the stack other than return addresses.  And non-address integer / FP data is unlikely to happen to be equal to a code address.  In any case, a false-positive isn't a disaster, it's just one extra line in the backtrace which you can ignore if it's obviously bogus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Because the BPs are a chain

They are *not*. It used to be that a frame pointer chain was used on `i386`, but for a few years now GCC defaults to `-fomit-frame-pointer` in optimized compiles even on `i386`. On `x86_64` the `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` was *never* the default in optimized code.

> this works fine if the call stack is totally inside my test programme's code.

This will *only* work if you compile without optimization (or with optimization if you *also* use `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`).

> I cannot explain why GDB can still work properly in such case

GDB (and [libunwind](https://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/)) uses `DWARF` unwind info, which you can examine with `readelf -wf a.out`.

Comment: Wow, this really answered my question, thank you. I said it's a chain because some articles said so. It seems the crt library was built with omit-frame-pointer option. OK, I will learn something about dwarf and libunwind before proceeding.